# I can not see all process on Unix using Apache

Tags: php, linux, bash, apache, perl

I am trying to get running process on server using Apache.
I have tried on PHP, Perl  and Bash script and used this commands :

```
exec('ps -u username -o pid,uname,cmd,pmem,pcpu,etime --sort=-pcpu  > test.txt'); 

exec('ps -u username -o pid,uname,cmd,pmem,pcpu,etime --sort=-pcpu', $output);

exec('ps -A', $output);
```

etc...

I only get all `/ USR / SBIN / HTTPD -k restart` processes.

But when I am trying this command on SSH (terminal), I am properly getting all processes.

I think problem is n Apache.

Anybody know how I can solve this problem and get all process using Apache.
Thanks advance

Comment: This is partially a permissions problem.  The web server usually runs as user "nobody" or "www" etc. and can not see all the processes like root can.

Answer (score 0):

```
# chcon -t unconfined_exec_t /sbin/httpd
```

Comment: @ChankeyPathak, could You expand on Your answer, please? What does it supposed to do?

Comment: chcon: cannot access `/sbin/httpd': No such file or directory

Answer (score -1):

use the command ps x
will list all active process

Comment: No it is not help. On SSH it is ok, but using Apache I still getting only restart
/usr/sbin/httpd -k restart
/usr/sbin/httpd -k restart
/usr/sbin/httpd -k restart
/usr/sbin/httpd -k restart
/usr/sbin/httpd -k restart
/usr/sbin/httpd -k restart
/usr/sbin/httpd -k restart
/usr/sbin/httpd -k restart
/usr/sbin/httpd -k restart
/usr/sbin/httpd -k restart
/usr/sbin/httpd -k restart
/usr/sbin/httpd -k restart
/usr/sbin/httpd -k restart
/usr/sbin/httpd -k restart